# regex to extract multiple symbols followed by word in a string -python

Tags: python, regex

I am writing a regex expression to extract symbols(#/-) followed by a word.For example, consider the string

```
s= "the amount is 5/10 of the original. The #2 number should be extracted on the dd/yy"
```

Regex expression is

```
r= re.search(r'(/|#).*\\s+',s)
```

The output which I got for the above is None where as I expected it to display

```
/10 #2 /yy
```

What is wrong in my regex expression.

Comment: First  ,your regex is wrong and  secondly , re.search returns None if no match is found and the regex object if match is found. Use re.findall() instead.

Comment: @BhawandeepSingla: I knew something is wrong in my regex. thats y it is returning None. Since I am not sure what is wrong, I am seeking help here so that someone could help me by pointing out my mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to match any 1+ non-whitespace chars (with `\S+`) after `/` or `#` (that can be matched with a `[/#]` character class):

```
[/#]\S+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KxMJH6/1).

**Tip**: If you do not want the `#` or `/` at the start to be preceded with any word char, prepend `\B` (a non-word boundary) at the pattern start: `\B[/#]\S+`.

Use `re.findall` in Python:

```
import re
s= "the amount is 5/10 of the original. The #2 number should be extracted on the dd/yy"
r = re.findall(r'[/#]\S+',s)
print(r)              # => ['/10', '#2', '/yy']
print(" ".join(r))    # => /10 #2 /yy
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/FdzI5G).

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
s = "the amount is 5/10 of the original. The #2 number should be extracted on the dd/yy"
r = re.findall(r'([/#]\S*)+', s)
print r
# ['/10', '#2', '/yy']
```

Regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/2lLwLf/1)

> What is wrong in my regex expression.

- `()` Means capturing group. use `[]` to match a character in a set
- `\\s` means match the string `\s`

Comment: This will match `/` and `#`, which is not what OP wants. And you don't need to escape `/` in a class. I suggest you copy Wiktor's answer *exactly*. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As you said :

extract symbols(#/-) `followed by a word`.

so you could use the Negative look ahead.

```
import re

pattern=r'/(?!/w).+?[^\s]|#\d'

strings= "the amount is 5/10 of the original. The #2 number should be extracted on the dd/yy"

match=re.findall(pattern,strings,re.M)

print(" ".join(list(match)))
```

Output:

```
/10 #2 /yy
```